# fetching youtube playlist id with php regex

Tags: php, regex, youtube, playlist

I am trying to fetch the playlist `id` from url and save it into a new variable.
For instance, if a user inputs this into a form, which then is submitted

`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7izsd5IXq8&playnext=1&list=PL6753173C0F0BE9ED`

I just want to grab `PL6753173C0F0BE9ED` and save it into a new variable. I tried to use explode to do this so it saved everything after the `&list=` but I am not having much luck.

Any ideas to do this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7izsd5IXq8&playnext=1&list=PL6753173C0F0BE9ED';

echo end(explode('=', $url));
```

Comment: Potential risk: Parameter order is mainly unimportant and `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7izsd5IXq8&list=PL6753173C0F0BE9ED&playnext=1` will (probably) lead to the same resource but yield another "playlist ID" (`1`). Thus, you're depending on the parameter order. (There is no guarantee, however, that depending on `list` as parameter name is better.)

Answer (score 5):

You could use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
$string = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7izsd5IXq8&playnext=1&list=PL6753173C0F0BE9ED';
$url = parse_url($string);
parse_str($url['query'],$q);
$list = $q['list'];
```

Comment: +1 Consider adding `PHP_URL_QUERY` as the second argument to `parse_url()`.

Comment: This is _much_ better than using a regular expression. Proper parsing is important! Definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7izsd5IXq8&playnext=1&list=PL6753173C0F0BE9ED';
$pl = preg_match('/list=(PL[a-f0-9]+)/i', $url, $match)
  ? $match[1]
  : false;
```

Comment: Consider replacing `list=` with `[?&]list=` in order not to match a potential future `oldList` parameter (or any other `?list` permutation).

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7izsd5IXq8&playnext=1&list=PL6753173C0F0BE9ED';
echo "URL = $url<br />";
$playlistID = explode("&list=", $url);
echo "playlistID = $playlistID[1]";
```

this seems to work

Comment: Same issue as pointed out in comment to @experimentX's answer: Consider the URL `http://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PL6753173C0F0BE9ED&v=A7izsd5IXq8&playnext=1`. (Not saying that this solution is *bound* to err.)